# How can I access the currently selected time range in grafana more cleanly?

Tags: angularjs, grafana

I'm embedding js into an html text panel, and would like to be able to reference the current time. However grafana is written in angular so there is a massive amount of abstraction and hiding of data; thus accessing the data I want has proven to be a mess.

The following works, but is probably all sorts of wrong to someone who knows angular at all. So is there a better way?

`angular.element($(".grafana-menu-refresh > a")).scope().ctrl.timeSrv.timeRange()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var rng = angular.element('grafana-app').injector().get('timeSrv').timeRange();
```